# Aggregate rows where primary key has multiple entries -SQL server

Tags: sql, sql-server

My primary key is a case_id in a ticketing system. My DB records a change to any attribute of the case_id's as a new entry. So any `case_id` may have multiple entries. The changed attribute gets recorded in `attribute` column and there's `from_string` and `to_string` columns which show changed values.

The issue is when extracting open cases which have recorded an `'open'` event but no `'close'` event in `description` column. Open and closing event get recorded by changes in different attributes.

I've tried

```sql
select case_id, create_date, attribute, from_string, to_string
from mydb
where   (
attribute    = 'status'
AND to_string       = 'opened' 
) --- opening event
AND NOT attribute = 'Root Cause' --- closing event
group by case_id
;
```

Comment: Sample data, and expected results, in a consumable format (not an image) will help us help you. Sounds like you might want a `NOT EXISTS`, or a `HAVING` clause; depending on  the results you are after.

Answer (score 1):

> The issue is when extracting open cases which have recorded an 'open' event but no 'close' event in description column.

I would expect code that looks like this:

```
select d.*
from mydb d
where d.attribute = 'status' and
      d.to_string = 'opened' and
      not exists (select 1
                  from mydb d2
                  where d2.case_id = d.case_id and
                        d2.attribute = 'status' and
                        d2.to_string = 'Root Cause'
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can achieve this using Common Table Expression.

```sql
;WITH CTE_CaseData AS
(
select case_id, create_date, attribute, from_string, to_string, 
CASE WHEN attribute    = 'status'
AND to_string       = 'opened' THEN 'Opened'
WHEN attribute = 'Root Cause' THEN 'Closed'
ELSE NULL END AS Status
from mydb
)
SELECT case_id, create_date, attribute, from_string, to_string
from CTE_CaseData as oc
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
(
SELECT * FROM CTE_CaseData WHERE case_id = oc.caseid AND status = 'Closed'
) AND status = 'Opened'
```